# How can I place a shape 5 times vetically above a bar?

Tags: pine-script

I want to show a shape which holds a shape 5 times vertically you can see it in the image. Is there anyone who can suggest how to do it in pine script ?

[image]

I have marked the shape its triangle shape

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code shows different ways of achieving the effect:

```
//@version=4
study("Lift text", "", true)
// Use U+200E (Decimal 8206) as a non-printing space after the last "\n".
// The line will become difficult to edit in the editor, but the character will be there.
// You can use https://unicode-table.com/en/tools/generator/ to generate a copy/pastable character.
plotshape(true, "", shape.arrowup,      location.abovebar, color.green,     text="A")
plotshape(true, "", shape.arrowup,      location.abovebar, color.lime,      text="B\n‎")

plotshape(bar_index % 2 == 0, "", shape.arrowdown, location.belowbar, #00000000, text="▼\n▼\n▼\n▼\n▼", textcolor = color.red)
plotchar(bar_index % 2 == 1, "bar_index % 2 == 0", "", location.belowbar, text = "▲\n▲\n▲\n▲\n▲\n")
```

[image]

In the editor, the code from the FAQ should appear like this, with the red squares indicating the Unicode white space character.

[image]

Comment: It does work. If you only need to show the five arrows on one condition, you can use one of the 2 last lines to achieve the effect. See my edit to the answer.

Comment: so sorry . I just followed the link didn't see your codes. It worked fine